# Requery combo boxes in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I've created two dependent combo boxes in a form. If you choose a `Category` in the first box, it will filter the list of `Products` available in the second. I've saved the Category-Product selections to a table called `Test`, where Categories get one row each.

What I'd like to do is display the Product in the Product combo box if you select a Category already in Test. For example, if you select Category=Condiments and Product=Ketchup in the form, it's added to Test. Then, the next time you select Category=Condiments in the form, the Products combo box (the box where you type, not the dropdown) will immediately show Ketchup. This only seems to work if I have one row in Test. If I add more rows, ProductComboBox does not change.

Here's how my form is constructed.

In the RowSource for CategoryComboBox, I select everything

```
Select * From CategoryTable
```

In the RowSource for ProductComboBox, I filter Products based on the Category selected

```
Select * From ProductTable Where ProductTable.CategoryID=[forms]![FormTest]![Category]
```

The form source is Products left joined to Category on CategoryID.

In the On Change event for CategoryComboBox and the On Current event for the form, I requery the ProductComboBox

```
ProductComboBox.Requery
```

However, using ProductComboBox.Requery only requeries the options available in the dropdown. It doesn't change the current combo box value after selecting a Category but before selecting a Product. How do I requery data from the table linked to the ControlSource? Is there a better VBA function than `Requery`, or do I need to use SQL in a macro?

Comment: Note that I still need the ability to enter data using the dropdown box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the OnChange Event of the first combobox, do the following:

```
 Private Sub category_Change()
      Dim myID As Long
      Me.ProductComboBox.Requery
      If Not IsNull(DLookup("ProductID", "tblTest", "CategoryID = " & me.Category)) Then
           Me.ProductComboBox = DLookup("ProductID", "tblTest", "CategoryID = " & me.Category)
      End If
 End Sub
```

Then to update your test table, in the event where you want to update the "default" option, put:

```
 CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE tblTest SET ProductID = " & Me.ProductComboBox & " WHERE CategoryID = " & Me.Category
```

This assumes that "tblTest" already has a record for each category.  If not, you can generate some checks and insert the category into the table.

Comment: Adding the If statement to the On Change event worked, thank you.